# Entity Framework and Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to (learn and use) Entity Framework and Linq (I don't know either very well...). Following MS tutorial: "Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database".

Everything looks fine, but my Linq results are returning 0 records. It seems so straight forward I am not sure what to fix? Is there a step I am missing?

(Azure db, if that matters...). After responding the the messagebox, the same table info is retrieved using ADO and it retrieves the records and I am able use Linq to create a ObservableCollection with no problem.

Entity Framework looks right:
[image]

Code:

```
private void test()
    {
        using (var db = new goboDBDataSet())
        {
            var query = from b in db.EstimateTbl
                        orderby b.ID
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("Estimate:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");

            MessageBox.Show($"Record Count: {query.Count()}");
        }
    }
```

My Console Output (and Messagebox "Count" returns 0):

Estimate:
Press any key to exit...

Comment: Make sure you are pointing at the database you think you are. Examine the db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.

Comment: and add `db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);` before your query.

Comment: thanks. I believe the connection string is correct since the date source preview is correct. David, db. - intellisence is not giving me Database as an option. Am I not connected to the right thing "var db = new goboDBDataSet()" ?

Answer (score 0):

I added a "Data Source", but I did not add an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and never created the proper ".edmx" file. Once I added an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" it was fine.